# Fill the .Formula's of an Excel Range with an array (of strings)

Tags: .net, excel

<sub>(In C# (though the language shouldn’t matter))</sub>

```
range.Formula = array;
```

does not result in an error, but behaves exactly like

```
range.Value2 = array;
```

: the Formulas appear like Values. Only after I do  <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>  on a cell, its Formula gets evaluated properly.

This is how I fill the array:

```
// setup (parameters)
int rows = cols = 10;
int rowStep = 1000*1000;
var array = new string[rows, cols];
// Fill the array.
for (long iRow = 1; iRow == rows; iRow++)
{
  for (long iCol = 1; iCol == cols; iCol++)
  {
    // Put a count in the cell.  E.g. "=A1+1+1000000"
    array[iRow-1, iCol-1] = "=A1+" + iCol + "+" + (iRow * rowStep);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me if I use `object[,]` instead of `string[,]`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The change I described solves the problem the question was about (it causes Excel to evaluate the formulas without any further action). I guess I worded my answer too cautiously (I only checked that it solves this particular instance, with my version of Excel) and you understood it as saying that I only got it to compile this way?

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why, but this (second line) fixed it:

```
range.Formula = array;
range.Formula = range.Formula;
```

Unfortunately this takes twice the time. Is there a better way which avoids that penalty?

<sub>The upper solution was informed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1200238/234309) post.</sub>

Comment: As @FunctorSalad suggests in his answer, change the type to `object`. If you do this, Excel will successfully evaluate `range.Formula = array`.